# How can I convert MP3 file to a Base64 encoded string?

Tags: audio, base64

I want to convert MP3 file which is less than 10 MB to a Base64 encoded string. I can only find image converters.

Can anybody suggest me an online tool which will do this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Look for "binary to base64" or "file to base64". For example, [this tool](http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/base64encode/).

Then precede raw base64 result with `data:audio/mpeg;base64,`

Comment: That 2nd sentence is key, was getting the encoded text but not the header. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

Use Notepad++, **first select the entire file (CTRL+A))** and then use the Base64 Encode option under the *plugins* menu:

[image: Main Menu - Plugins - MIME Tools - Base64 Encode]