# Play a beep sound when new record in MySQL - HTML table

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, symfony

So, I have a PHP - Symfony 3 project connected to a MySQL Database through an API to let customers place orders through an Android APP. I need the Browser to play a beep sound when a new order has been placed (orders are shown in an HTML table) So I guess the sound has to be played using Javascript when the table changes. Any ideas on how to accomplish this? Thank you in advance. I will post the index view code below if it helps

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
<h1 class="page-header">Listado de Aderezos</h1>

<table class="table table-striped table-responsive" id="data">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Descripcion</th>
            <th style="display:none;">Deleteat</th>
            <th>Acciones</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% set cont = 0 %}
    {% for Aderezo in aderezos %}
        <tr>
            <td><a href="{{ path('aderezo_show', { 'id': Aderezo.id }) }}">{{ Aderezo.id }}</a></td>
            <td>{{ Aderezo.nombre }}</td>
            <td>{{ Aderezo.descripcion }}</td>
            <td>{{ Aderezo.deleteAt }}</td>
            <td>
                <div class="btn-group">

                            <a id="viewedit{{ cont }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" href="{{ path('aderezo_show', { 'id': Aderezo.id }) }}">show</a>
                            {% set cont = cont + 1 %}

                            <a id="viewedit{{ cont }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" href="{{ path('aderezo_edit', { 'id': Aderezo.id }) }}">edit</a>
                            {% set cont = cont + 1 %}
                                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger" href="{{ path('aderezo_delete', { 'id': Aderezo.id }) }}">Eliminar</a>                    </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>

<a class="btn btn-block btn-lg" href="{{ path('aderezo_new') }}">Crear Nuevo Aderezo</a>

<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#data').DataTable({

            destroy:true,
            language:{
                "sProcessing":     "Procesando...",
                "sLengthMenu":     "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
                "sZeroRecords":    "No se encontraron resultados",
                "sEmptyTable":     "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
                "sInfo":           "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
                "sInfoEmpty":      "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
                "sInfoFiltered":   "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
                "sInfoPostFix":    "",
                "sSearch":         "Buscar:",
                "sUrl":            "",
                "sInfoThousands":  ",",
                "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
                "oPaginate": {
                    "sFirst":    "Primero",
                    "sLast":     "Último",
                    "sNext":     "Siguiente",
                    "sPrevious": "Anterior"
                },
                "oAria": {
                    "sSortAscending":  ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
                    "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
                }
            }

        });
    });

</script>
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        var contador = {{ cont }};
        while (contador >= 0){


            if ( $('#viewedit'+contador).text() =='show'){
                $('#viewedit'+contador).text("Ver");
            }

            if ($('#viewedit'+contador).text()=='edit'){
                $('#viewedit'+contador).text("Editar");
            }
            contador = contador - 1;
        }


    });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Depends how quickly you need it. Can use ajax long polling (longer interval) or websockets for instant updates. Ajax is simpler to implement. Both are easily researched

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a simple sound you can base64 encode the binary data of the file into a string. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878404/how-can-i-convert-mp3-file-to-base64-encoded-string).

Then play the sound through Javascript. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17762763/play-wav-sound-file-encoded-in-base64-with-javascript).